# Editing the Comment Reply Link

Tags: comments, nofollow

Just found this site via the WP-Hackers List, been using WordPress for years (make a living partially thanks to it) and never stumbled on this site!

Posted this on the WP-Hackers list, but didn't find a solution.

I know WordPress 3.1 has removed the nofollow attribute from the
comment Reply link (WordPress 3.1 beta looks good), but was working on
something theme wise that should also work with removing the nofollow
attribute from the link for WordPress 3.0.3 and below, but can't get
it working.

from /wp-includes/comment-template.php

```
 } else {
  $link = "<a rel='nofollow' class='comment-reply-link' href='" . get_permalink($post->ID) . "#$respond_id' onclick='return addComment.moveForm(\"$add_below-$post->ID\", \"0\", \"$respond_id\", \"$post->ID\")'>$reply_text</a>";
 }
 return apply_filters('post_comments_link', $before . $link . $after, $post);
```

In WordPress 3.1 rel='nofollow' has been removed from the above code. I'm trying to achieve the same at theme level for WordPress 3.0.3 and below.

Basically adding this code to the comments loop as a test works:

```
$comment->comment_content = str_replace('nofollow', 'Test One',$comment->comment_content);
```

This removes the text nofollow from a comments body.

I tried

```
$comment_reply_link->reply_text  = str_replace('Reply', 'Test Two',$comment_reply_link->reply_text );
```

As another test to replace the anchor text of the Reply link to
confirm I'm on the right track.

Didn't work.

and

```
$comment_reply_link->link  = str_replace('nofollow', '',$comment_reply_link->link );
```

to delete the nofollow part of the rel attribute.

Didn't work either

Tried a variety of permutations with no joy.

Any ideas?

David

Comment: The site is only several months old and still in beta. :)

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers David, have only recently joined myself... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

functions.php:

```
function remove_nofollow($link, $args, $comment, $post){
  return str_replace("rel='nofollow'", "", $link);
}

add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'remove_nofollow', 420, 4);
```

Comment: 420 priority, huh? :)

Comment: Thanks AmbitiousAmoeba, that worked perfectly. Been stuck on that problem for ages.